# How to apply conditional treatment with line.endswith(x) where x is a regex result?

Tags: regex, if-statement, for-loop, python-2.7

I am trying to apply conditional treatment for lines in a file (symbolised by list values in a list for demonstration purposes below) and would like to use a regex function in the `endswith(x)` method where x is a range `page-[1-100])`.

```
import re
lines = ['http://test.com','http://test.com/page-1','http://test.com/page-2']
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('http') and line.endswith('page-2'):
        print line
```

So the required functionality is that if the value starts with `http` and ends with a page in the range of `1-100` then it will be returned.

**Edit:**  After reflecting on this, I guess the corollary questions are:

- How do I make a regex pattern ie `page-[1-100]` a variable?
- How do I then use this variable eg `x` in `endswith(x)`

**Edit:**

This is not an answer to the original question (ie it does not use `startswith()` and `endswith()`), and I have no idea if there are problems with this, but this is the solution I used (because it achieved the same functionality):

```
import re
lines = ['http://test.com','http://test.com/page-1','http://test.com/page-100']
for line in lines:
    match_beg = re.search( r'^http://', line)
    match_both = re.search( r'^http://.*page-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|100)$', line)
    if match_beg and not match_both:
        print match_beg.group()
    elif match_beg and match_both:
        print match_both.group()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know python well enough to paste usable code, but as far as the regular expression is concerned, this is rather trivial to do:

```
page-(?:[2-9]|[1-9]\d|100)$
```

What this expression will match:

- `page-` is just a fixed string that will be matched 1:1 (case insensitive if you set Options for that).
- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that's just used for separating the following branching.
- `|` all act as "either or" with the expressions being to their left/right.
- `[2-9]` will match this numerical range, i.e. 2-9.
- `[1-9]\d` will match any two Digit number (10-99); `\d` matches any digit.
- `100` is again a plain and simple match.
- `$` will match the line end or end of string (again based on settings).

Using this expression you don't use any specific "ends with" functionality (that's given through using `$`).

Considering this will have to parse the whole string anyway, you may include the "begins with" check as well, which shouldn't cause any additional overhead (at least none you'd notice):

```
^http://.*page-(?:[2-9]|[1-9]\d|100)$
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the line or string (based on settings).
- `http://` is once again a plain match.
- `.` will match any character.
- `*` is a quantifier "none or more" for the previous expression.

Answer (score 1):

To get you going in the right direction, the Regex that matches your needed range of pages is:

```
^http.*page-([2-9]?|[1-9][0-9]|100)$
```

this will match lines that start with `http` and end with `page-<2 to 100>` inclusive.

Comment: I think you mean `^http.*page-([2-9]?|[1-9][0-9]|100)$`

Comment: With that `?` you'd also accept something such as `http...page-`. I'm not sure that's intentional.

Comment: I don't know how to apply this to achieve required results. I am using `startswith()` and `endswith()` just because i can understand that logic and therefore just need to know how to make `page-2` a variable matching a regex pattern that could be any page from `page-1` to `page-100` in the context of `endswith(x)` where x is that variable.